How do I keep my progress bar indicator from showing outside of it's rounded corners?
My progress bar when I use rounding overflows its border:

My fix (a transparent arc outside rounded rectangle using pygame.draw.arc) still leaves a part visible. The arc function uses a rectangle, so I calculate its position and size:
# I stored the 4 border radiuses in a dictionary.
rad = sqrt(border_radius['border_top_left_radius']**2*2)
# It can also be written as
rad = sqrt(2)*border_radius['border_top_left_radius']

And subtracted border radius to get distance from corner to bounding square's vertex:
dist = round(rad-border_radius['border_top_left_radius'])

I drew the arc:
pygame.draw.arc(
    self.image,
    (0,0,0,0),
    pygame.Rect(
        -dist,
        -dist,
        border_radius['border_top_left_radius']*2+dist,
        border_radius['border_top_left_radius']*2+dist),
    math.radians(90), math.radians(180),
    dist
)

But it still overflows its rounded corner (black to illustrate):

Maybe the rounded corners are not exact circles?

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but the below code produces a progress bar which is perfectly enclosed by the progress bar box.
Instead of drawing arcs, I have just used the same dictionary of border radii for both drawing the progress bar box, as well as the progress bar itself. This is running on pygame-ce 2.4.1.
Here is a minimal example:
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))

border_radius = {
    "border_top_left_radius": 20,
    "border_top_right_radius": 20,
    "border_bottom_left_radius": 20,
    "border_bottom_right_radius": 20,
}

progress_bar_rect = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 300, 80)

bar = pygame.Rect(progress_bar_rect.left, progress_bar_rect.top, 80, progress_bar_rect.height)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill("black")    
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "green", bar, **border_radius)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "gray", progress_bar_rect, 5, **border_radius)
    pygame.display.update()

Program result linked here
Few other things to keep in mind:

It would be useful to provide the version of pygame you're running, especially due to Community Edition being a thing.
FRect (part of the community edition of pygame) may be preferable since floats are respected for dimensions, unlike Rect; this won't solve your rounding issues necessarily but does mean you can be more precise.


I don't know if this is an acceptable variant for you, but you could use an image that has the edges in a certain color and your progress bar on it with the interior being transparent. That way, you could take a surface, draw a rect with the color you want, blit the image on top of it, and make the edges transparent after that using a colorkey.
Here's an example:
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

# image with the frame of your progress bar (colored edge, transparent interior)
img = pygame.image.load("your_img.png").convert_alpha()
# surf for your progress bar
surf = pygame.Surface(img.get_size())

# define a color and a progress for testing
progress_bar_color = (0, 255, 0)
current_progress = 0.6

# draw your progress rect
pygame.draw.rect(surf, progress_bar_color, [0, 0, surf.get_width() * current_progress, surf.get_height()])
# blit the frame on top of it
surf.blit(img, (0,0))

# set the colorkey to make the edges transparent now
edge_color = (255,255,255)
surf.set_colorkey(edge_color)

# display it
screen.blit(surf, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()

done = False
while not done:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

Please note that whatever you choose as the colorkey will be made completely transparent, so the frame of your progress bar mustn't contain the colorkey you use to make the edges transparent. Otherwise, parts of it will turn transparent as well.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
